CosmosDB Python SDK replace_item and upsert_item delete the record instead of updating it
I have a script that fetches a certain record, if it exists, and modifies its properties before updating it in the database using replace_item or upsert_item. If I fetch the entire record, change the properties and use that record as both the item and body, it works properly.
But, if I decide I to just fetch the ID of the document (to save on RU), put the id into a new object with the adequate properties, then update using the id and new document, the document gets deleted inexplicably.
The problematic variant of the code can be found below:
dbList = list(dbContainer.query_items(
    query="SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE c.something = @something",
    parameters=[
        dict(name='@something', value=whatever)
    ],
    enable_cross_partition_query=True
    ))

    if dbList:
    # Update the item if it exists, considering we must have only one
        record = dbList[0]
        record['property'] = newProperty
        try:
            container.replace_item(item=record['id'], body=record)
        except exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError as e:
            print(f"Failed to update record. Details: {e.message}")

I tried using upsert_item instead of replace_item but I get the same outcome. Selecting by ID and setting item=record gives me a KeyError.

KeyError raises when the key or path doesn't exist.

replace_item() can't change the partition key's value. If the partition key path isn't /id then you don't have the partition key in your record (since you only retrieved id), and won't be able to replace it. Note that, even if your replace operation did work, you'd lose all your other properties, as you're replacing the document with just id and 'property`

Can you add the KeyError details?

@DavidMakogon It works, because the partition key path is, indeed, /id. You're right on the second part, as I was practically removing the something property each time I updated a record, thereby leaving a bunch of useless records in the collection that were not getting queried.

Yes @S.Ptr, I agree what David said, replace_item() cannot be worked with the partition key value and without the correct partition key, you cannot perform a replace operation. If the partition key is id and try to change its value, then it throws an error. Below is the code which successfully works if the searched item is found then it replaces with the new value as you can see in the below output.
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient, exceptions

endpoint = "*****"
key = "*****"

client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
database_name = "firstDb"
container_name = "firstCont1"

database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

dbList = list(container.query_items(
    query="SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.something = @something",
    parameters=[
        dict(name='@something', value="value1")
    ],
    enable_cross_partition_query=True
))

if dbList:
    record = dbList[0]
    
    record['property'] = "updated_value1"
    
    try:
        container.replace_item(item=record['id'], body=record)
        print(f"Document updated successfully: {record}")
    except exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError as e:
        print(f"Failed to update document. Details: {e.message}")
else:
    print("No document found with the specified query.")


Data stored in Azure Cosmos DB Container:
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "something": "value1",
        "property": "initial_value1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "something": "value2",
        "property": "initial_value2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "something": "value3",
        "property": "initial_value3"
    }
]

Data in Azure Cosmos DB after execution of the code:
Output:
Document updated successfully:
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "something": "value1",
        "property": "updated_value1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "something": "value2",
        "property": "initial_value2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "something": "value3",
        "property": "initial_value3"
    }
]

